# Why isn't text overflow being applied to my inline element?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a template like the image below, I want to add text-overflow: ellipsis; feature to the name

[image]

But this feature is not added, where am I doing wrong? I want the arrangement of the sections to remain unchanged

```css
p.meta {
  font-size: 14px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
}

p.meta img.avatar {
  position: inherit;
  width: 32px;
  float: right;
  height: auto;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 7px;
  background: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
}

p.meta strong.woocommerce-review__author {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #000000;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 12ch;
}

p.meta em.woocommerce-review__verified {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  color: #000000;
}

p.meta time.woocommerce-review__published-date {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #000000;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<p class="meta">
  <img alt="" src="http://2.gravatar.com/avatar/22be747127f7682d97dcfdba7c349038?s=32&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g" srcset="http://2.gravatar.com/avatar/22be747127f7682d97dcfdba7c349038?s=64&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g 2x" class="avatar avatar-32 photo" height="32" width="32"
    loading="lazy" decoding="async">
  <strong class="woocommerce-review__author">admin</strong>
  <em class="woocommerce-review__verified verified"> | verified owner</em>
  <time class="woocommerce-review__published-date" datetime="2023/3/10 15:53:05">2023/3/10</time>
</p>
```

Comment: If you check out your output in the dev tools, like in chrome, the solution is handed to you: `width`: "The `display: inline` property prevents width from having an effect. Try setting display to something other than inline." Setting it to `inline-block` solves your issue. However, the text is too short to ever be cut off (admin is 5 characters long, and you width is about 12)

Comment: In this case, verified owner and date will fall down, I want the sections to remain unchanged

Comment: Then you can't do it? What do you want me to say? This is why your `text-overflow: ellipsis` isn't working. `inline-block` should not cause a reflow unless it breaks on a line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check inside your dev tools, you will see that `width` isn't being applied because of the `display` type:

[image: Dev tools show why it isn't working]

Simply adding `display: inline-block` solves your issue of the overflow not working as the box now respects the `width` you gave it. You also need to add some more characters, as admin is `5` long, and your width is `12`, so that overflow is never going to show up in your example.

```css
p.meta {
  font-size: 14px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
}

p.meta img.avatar {
  position: inherit;
  width: 32px;
  float: right;
  height: auto;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 7px;
  background: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
}

p.meta strong.woocommerce-review__author {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #000000;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 12ch;
  display: inline-block;
}

p.meta em.woocommerce-review__verified {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  color: #000000;
}

p.meta time.woocommerce-review__published-date {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #000000;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<p class="meta">
  <img alt="" src="http://2.gravatar.com/avatar/22be747127f7682d97dcfdba7c349038?s=32&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g" srcset="http://2.gravatar.com/avatar/22be747127f7682d97dcfdba7c349038?s=64&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g 2x" class="avatar avatar-32 photo" height="32" width="32"
    loading="lazy" decoding="async">
  <strong class="woocommerce-review__author">admin with more letters than 12</strong>
  <em class="woocommerce-review__verified verified"> | verified owner</em>
  <time class="woocommerce-review__published-date" datetime="2023/3/10 15:53:05">2023/3/10</time>
</p>
```

Comment: If you look carefully, you can see that verified owner has moved out of the box a bit and is trending down, https://imgur.com/a/lCPRJjL

Comment: And you want me to solve that too? Use a flexbox with align-items: center or something… your focus was the text overflow, I answered why it isn’t working.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Although I already knew this, but because of the problem I said, I said maybe I was doing it wrong, but you did the same thing. I approve the answer for your trouble

Comment: I can't know you 'tried this' if you don't mention it in your question. Aligning it again shouldn't be too hard, you can just use a flexbox around the thing and it will work I think. But you can't get around browser restrictions - inline elements cannot have a width really, as their inline contents flow to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

```css
p.meta {
  font-size: 14px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  float: right;      
}

p.meta img.avatar {
  position: inherit;
  width: 32px;
  float: right;
  height: auto;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 7px;
  background: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
}

p.meta strong.woocommerce-review__author {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #000000;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 12ch;
  float: right;
}

p.meta em.woocommerce-review__verified {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  color: #000000;
}

p.meta time.woocommerce-review__published-date {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #000000;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<p class="meta">
  <img alt="" src="http://2.gravatar.com/avatar/22be747127f7682d97dcfdba7c349038?s=32&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g" srcset="http://2.gravatar.com/avatar/22be747127f7682d97dcfdba7c349038?s=64&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g 2x" class="avatar avatar-32 photo" height="32" width="32"
    loading="lazy" decoding="async">
  <strong class="woocommerce-review__author">admin</strong>
  <em class="woocommerce-review__verified verified"> | verified owner</em>
  <time class="woocommerce-review__published-date" datetime="2023/3/10 15:53:05">2023/3/10</time>
</p>
```